# Find and replace using find and sed

Tags: sed, replace

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056052/2081511) shared how to remove html comments from a file at the command line.

```
sed -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba' file.html
```

I'm trying to extend that to remove html comments from all files in a directory, but I'm having a hard time. Some of my attempts include:

```
 find /my/folder/plus/subfolders -name "*.html" -exec "sed -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba'"
```

And based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/find-sed-search-and-replace), I've tried this approach too:

```
find /my/folder/plus/subfolders -name "*.html" -exec sed -i s/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba {} +
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: put the `sed` script in a file and call it from `find` or xargs. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace with sed in directory and sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to add the in place option `-i` and change the file to `{}`.

```
find /my/folder/plus/subfolders -name "*.html" -exec sed -i -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba' {} +
```

Comment: Are all these parameters, like `-i`, `-e`, `{}`, and `+` under the `find` command or the `sed` command? Is everything to the right of sed now operating under sed?

Comment: The `-exec` option is ended with `+` (or `\;`). So the `sed` command is `sed -i -e :a -re 's/<!--.*?-->//g;/<!--/N;//ba' {}`, where `{}` is replaced by the files.